# Prove that an element in the quotient field is actually in the ring itself

Tags: abstract-algebra, noetherian

Let $R$ be a noetherian integral domain and $K$ the quotient field of $R.$ Suppose $f \in K.$ Suppose for each maximal ideal $M$ of $R,$ we can find $h,k\in R$ so that $f = h/k$ and $k \not\in M$. Show $f \in R.$

Note: $R$ is not assumed a UFD!

My attempt:
I tried to prove that the summation of ideals generated by all the k that are not in some maximal ideals is the whole ring. But I dont know how to use that to move on. Also, I do not understand how to show an element is in the ring. I tried to prove that k has to divide h, but since R is not a UFD, I am not sure to achieve that.

Comment: Use mathjax. ${}{}$

Comment: do you mean that you have seen similar question on mathjax?

Comment: They meant that you should use the math-formatting of the site, which @ThomasAndrews just did :)

Comment: I see. My bad..

Comment: You can show that if there is a $k\notin M,$ then there is a $k$ such that $k-1\in M.$ Not sure if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $I=\{a\in R: af\in R\}\subseteq R$. This is clearly an ideal of $R$. If we can show that $I=R$ then it means $1\in I$ and so $f\in R$, as we want. So suppose $I\ne R$. Then $I$ is contained in some maximal ideal $M$. By assumption, there are $h,k\in R$ such that $f=\frac{h}{k}$ and $k\notin M$. But then note that:

$kf=k\frac{h}{k}=h\in R$

And so $k\in I\subseteq M$, a contradiction.

Note that you don't even need $R$ to be Noetherian.

Comment: Thanks!!!! I failed to define the ideal . That why I struggled for so long. I have proved that  is the entire ring by proving ideal generated by all the k is the whole ring and k is definitely in .

Answer (score 1):

All you need is for $R$ to be a domain. We'll prove
$\newcommand{\m}{\mathfrak{m}}$

> **Proposition.** $R=\bigcap_{\m}R_\m$.

In the above, the intersection runs over all maximal ideals of $R$, and we identify $R_\m$ with the subring $\{\frac rs\mid r\in R, s\in R\setminus\m\}$ of $K$. One inclusion is obvious: the canonical maps $R\hookrightarrow R_\m\hookrightarrow K$ show that $R$ is a subset of the intersection $\bigcap_{\m}R_\m$.

The reverse inclusion is equivalent to
$$
K \setminus R
\subset 
K\setminus \bigcap_{\m}R_\m
\quad\text{i.e.}\quad
K \setminus R
\subset
\bigcup_{\m}~(K\setminus R_\m)
$$
So consider $x\in K\setminus R$ and put $J=\{r\in R\mid rx\in R\}$. Then $J$ is a proper ideal of $R$: it's obviously an ideal of $R$ and not all of $R$ since $1\notin J$. By Zorn's lemma, $J$ is contained in some maximal ideal $\m_0$. The claim is now that $x\in K\setminus R_{\m_0}$. Otherwise we could write $x=\frac rs$ with $r\in R$, $s\in R\setminus\m_0$, but then $sx=r\in R$ and $s\in J\subset\m_0$, which is a contradiction. Therefore $x\in K\setminus R_{\m_0}$ and we are done.